# React - How to pass another component into generic component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to remove/separate layout from filter dropdown component as it makes generic component completely useless outside of some specific use-case

`transfer-assets.tsx`

```
        <FilterDropdown
          data={pensionFunds?.pension_funds}
        />
```

`filter-dropdown.tsx`

```
interface FilterDropdownProps {
  /* eslint-disable  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
  data: any[] | undefined
  dropdownDataLayout: JSX.Element
}

export const FilterDropdown = ({
  data,
  dropdownDataLayout: DropdownDataLayout,
}: FilterDropdownProps) => {
  
  return (
    <SelectField>
      {data?.map((option: Record<string, any>, index: number) => (
         // How to render dropdownDataLayout here ? My idea but is not working -> <DropdownDataLayout option={option} key={index} />
      ))}
    </SelectField>
  )
}
```

My idea is to pass prop like this, from `transfer-assets.tsx`

```
  const TransferAssetsLayout = ({
    option,
    index,
  }: TransferAssetsLayoutProps) => {
    return (
      ...
    )
  }

        <FilterDropdown
          data={pensionFunds?.pension_funds}
          dropdownDataLayout={TransferAssetsLayout}
        />
```

, but this is not working because I need to pass `option` and `key` props how to pass props `options` and `key` props to the `filter-dropdown.tsx` component in order to render the desired layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to be typing `dropdownDataLayout` as `React.FunctionComponent` (the function that renders a JSX element) rather than JSX.Element (the JSX node materialized by the function). You can provide a generic definition which restricts the React component passed to only those which provide a known set of props (in this case, I'm reusing `TransferAssetsLayoutProps` but you may want a more generic interface that each of your layouts conforms to)

```
interface FilterDropdownProps {
  /* eslint-disable  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
  data: any[] | undefined
  dropdownDataLayout: React.FC<TransferAssetsLayoutProps>
}
```

Then you can use [React.createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) to materialize it - JSX like `<TransferAssetsLayout {...props} />` is just syntactic sugar for `React.createElement(TransferAssetsLayout, props)`, so if you have a function component in a variable, rather than using JSX, you can just call `React.createElement` directly.

```
return (
  <SelectField>
    {data?.map((option: Record<string, any>, index: number) => (
       React.createElement(dropdownDataLayout, {option, key: index})
    ))}
  </SelectField>
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my `dropdownDataLayout` is in `transfer-assets.tsx` page, how to pass it as a prop?

Comment: `dropdownDataLayout` is a prop on `FilterDropdown`, you're passing the `TransferAssetsLayout` as its value.